# Does the topological fundamental group on schemes provide any interesting information?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm just learning my first things about the étale fundamental group. And while I see that the usual fundamental group is not really a "natural" thing to do in the category of schemes I wonder wether it might still provide useful information on the underlying topological spaces or wether the zariski topology is just too coarse. Maybe more precisely I'm asking wether something like: "The usual fundamental group is trivial for all (or a really huge class of) schemes" is true.
Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Zariski topology is just too coarse. For example, the Zariski topology on any algebraic curve is just the cofinite topology.

In fact, as I recently learned on MO, any topological space with a generic point (in particular, the spectrum of any integral domain) is contractible.

Comment: This is in the same vein as how all constant sheaves are flasque on irreducible spaces, so that singular cohomology is equally useless.

Comment: Of course, the second of my two statements (about the singular cohomology groups vanishing) follows from your statement :)

Comment: I can't find this MO post you speak of.  Can you explain why having a generic point makes a space contractible?